# Equivalence relation in a simple directed graph $D$

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, equivalence-relations, directed-graphs

I have written my proof, but I'm still not sure if it's rigth:

Determine if for all directed graphs $D$ the following relation $R$ defined in $V(D)$ is an equivalence relation: $xRy$ if and only if $x=y$ or there is an $xy$-path directed.

- Reflexivity: It's reflexive because if $x = x'$ and then $x' = x$ then by definition it holds, but not sure about the path because since $D$ is simple, there can't be the $x$ $x$ edge
- Simetry: It is not symetric because a directed path existing from $x$ to $y$ does not imply that there is some directed path from $y$ to $x$.
- Transitivity : We uppose there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$ and a directed path from $y$ to $z$. Then we procede to cancontenate this paths and we get de $xz$ path. But here I'm not sure because this might not be a path because it could possibly have repeated edges if some edge or edges appeared in both paths involved in the concatenation

Any help?

Comment: All you need is just one graph for which the relation is not symmetric. A single such example proves that the relation is not necessarily an equivalence relation. You don't have to analyze all three conditions if you already know that one of them doesn't always hold.

Comment: But for your proof, it's not enough to assert that the relation need not be symmetric. You need to give an example (which is of course very easy).

Comment: Oh thanks I think I found it, I thought that I had to show everythinh

Comment: To prove that a relation is an equivalence relation, you have to verify all $3$ properties. To show that a relation is _not_ an equivalence relation, it suffices to show one of the $3$ properties fails.